# d20pfsrd Discord Bot Scraper Abstraction and Deployment

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, raspberry-pi

I wrote a discord bot that listens for links to the d20pfsrd rulebook in discord chat, checks if they are feats or magic, and then scrapes the page, formats it, and spits it back into chat as formatted text. The pages I'm checking are formulaic enough, so even though the cheerio selectors I'm using are probably fairly brittle, it seems to work in most cases. The text formatters are some ugly beasts though (though the logic is probably unique), and the axios calls could use some cleaning up as well.

My problem is as follows: I suspected a good 40% of the code can be refactored out of existence if I properly generalized it. My solution was to do something that could probably be described as an abuse of the spread operator:

```
async function getPage(msg, url){
  let message = "placeholder";
  await axios.get(url).then( (response) => {
      message = responder(...selectResponder(url), response);
    } 
    ).catch((error) => {
      console.error(error.message);
    });
  sendMessage(message, msg);
  
}
```

A week later I'm now realizing I wrote the functions in a way that causes them to read backwards? Aesthetics aside, this is how it ends up working out:

```
function selectResponder(siteUrl){
  if (siteUrl.startsWith("https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/")){
      return feats.featsConfig;
    } else if (siteUrl.startsWith("https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/")){
      return magic.magicConfig;
  }
}

function responder(parser, formatter, messageFormatter, response){
    const replyData = parser(response.data);
    const formattedData = formatter(replyData);
    return messageFormatter(formattedData);
}
```

The idea is that as much unique logic as I could separate out exists in magic.js and feats.js as possible. How can I clean this section up? The github repo is [here](https://github.com/JasonMadeSomething/discord-pathfinder-searcher) and I would love and feedback on the entire project. I did most of that because I thought it as weird to have a big if block here and duplicating the axios calls:

```
client.on('message', msg => {
  

  if(validateUrl(msg.content)){
    const siteUrl = encodeURI(msg.content);
    getPage(msg, siteUrl);
  }
  

});
```

Also I wrote up [this gist](https://gist.github.com/JasonMadeSomething/4e557989e3b9fbd71a0bd21ec2168aac) on how I deployed it to a raspberry pi. That works, so suggestions on how to improve it would be greatly appreciated

In broad strokes this program:

1. Listens for a message
2. Validates the message
3. Gets the page content at the message url
4. Parses the page content
5. Re-formats the page content
6. Converts the page content into a message
7. Sends the message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it. Move the logic about which pages a parser consumes into the code for said parser. Also organizing your helper files into objects could reduce complexity in terms of the number of variables you pass around but that's more a matter of personal preference.

````
class SpecificPageParser {
    match(url) {
        return (
           url.startswith('https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/') &&
           !url.endsWith('/magic/')
        );
    }
    format(response) {
        // do your parsing stuff
        const formatted = {...response,'extra':'info'};
        return formatted;
    }
}

const responders = [new SpecificPageParser(),new SomeOtherParser()];

async function getPage(msg, url){
    try {
        const responder = responders.find(responder=>responder.match(url));
        if (!responder) return;
        const response = await axios.get(url);
        const message = responder.format(response);
        sendMessage(message, msg);
    }
    catch(error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
  }
```
````

Comment: So i've been trying to implement this, and I'm noticing that my reflex seems to be to recreate the ungeneralized responder in the format function of each parser class. The logic of responder would be nearly identical for both classes with only the function names varying. Is that simply the trade off at play here, or can I generalize the passing of the data around to the parsing steps so each class can implement it? (would that be an abstract class?)

Comment: I managed to implement the classes for the parsers, and I'm seeing how it cuts way down on the amount of code I used. I suppose I would have to write a lot more if I want to avoid replicating the 3 lines of the formatter logic

Comment: If the logic ends up similar with only minor differences in specific functions you could add the specific functions as methods on your parsers and then writing your overall format() function once using the generic methods.